# Manufacturer identification by logo: GP

Tags: diodes, identification

I have some diodes with this logo, and I am trying to identify the manufacturer. I've done quite a bit of searching, and, so far, my best guess was Green Power, but that was a bust. Does anyone recognize it?

The diode is about 4.6 inches tall and 1.8 inches wide.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also provide the other markings and dimensions of the part?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I've added dimensions and another picture to the post. Additional markings read "68A9515P1", "0918", and "INDIA"

Comment: [This site](https://sbindustrialsupply.com/shop/new-national-electronics-c290pbx-rectifier-9903-8m73/) sells a similar part with the same symbol. They claim the manufacturer is National Electronics, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: @nanash1 thanks! I at least emailed the site, just in case they have more info.